# How to get UIPageControl transparent indicator in the middle?

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I want to create a UIPageControl like in the following image.

[image]

**How to get UIPageControl transparent indicator in the middle?**

Comment: Did you try some custom page control like FXPageControl? https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXPageControl

Comment: @lucaslt89 I do not see how to get the hole in the middle.

Comment: You'll need to use custom images for that

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : you can't. `UIPageControl` can't be customized.

But you can use one of the many alternatives [available on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=Page%20Control).